# How to query all children on NestJS

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to build this working example from the TypeORM documentation using NestJS: https://typeorm.io/#/entity-inheritance (Concrete table inheritance)

This creates three tables: photo, question and post. Post is supposed to be the parent class, but when I'm querying it using find it doesn't return anything, while I would be expecting to query all questions and photos.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concrete Table Inheritance is about having abstract class which contains all default fields and then can be extended with other entities.

If you want to load questions and photos (relations) of some post, you should include them in post query, for example:

```
const posts = await this.postRepository.find({ relations: ['photos', 'questions'] });
```